# Show popup while app is in background

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing an application where I want to show a popup screen at a regular frequency selected by the user, even if my application is closed.

I am able to show a popup screen in regular intervals when my application is in the foreground. But I am not able to show a popup screen when my application is in the background.

I tried UIApplication.requestBackground() method, which invokes Application.deactivate() method, and on that method I am calling a timer. But it is not giving me any output, not even exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [UiApplication](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html).pushGlobalScreen() to get a popup to appear when your app is in the background.

Comment: Thank you sir. I used pushGlobalScreen(new POPUP(),0,0) instead of pushScreen(new POPUP()) and on shifting to the backGround, i got the popUPScreen. After using pushGlobalScreen(), i found that there is no need to create class extending Application class and overriding its deactivate() method to call timer. Setting timer on button click and calling UiApplication.requestBackGround() on Screen.onClose() is doing the job. Is this the correct way to implement this functionality?